# Laravel passport auth_token not saved

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am working on a Laravel site and I have been the LoginController. Although I obtain the auth_token at login - it doesn't allow me to call the user method - it claims the user is "unauthetnicated"

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication

I followed some documentation claiming that its unauthenticated because I need to group commands in the route?

"This is because we are not authenticated to access that route"
https://www.toptal.com/laravel/passport-tutorial-auth-user-access

but then it throws an error with ['cors', 'json.response']?

my route/api.php looks like this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::group(['middleware' => [/*'cors', 'json.response'*/]], function () {

    // public routes

    // get auth token, POST, /login
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->middleware('auth:api');
});


Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    // our routes to be protected will go in here
});
```

and my logincontroller is like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    //

    function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required']
        ]);

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        //if user not found or the request password and user password does not match
        if(!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect']
            ]);
        }

        return $user->createToken('Auth Token')->accessToken;
    }

    function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
    }


}
```

Comment: "it doesn't allow me to call the user method", when and where?

Comment: when I call the user method it comes back - unauthenticated in the postman

Comment: when you call what user method in what code? and you are passing the token with the request?

Comment: yes - I pass the token in the header as part of the bearer - its something to do with the way the routes are set?

Comment: have you adjusted you `api` guard to use the `passport` driver already?

Comment: yes - but the auth_token doesn't look like its written to the db?